# How to change the environment in Tests script of last request of the collection

Tags: postman, environment

Some set of the requests are to run under few environments , so i want to make few iterations in collection runner and in a test script of last request to change environment , to make next iteration run on next environment -
Need your help to change environment through script if it is possible

Comment: I don't think this is something that's supported in Postman

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment, but there is a workaround (copied from the [Postman Community](https://community.postman.com/t/change-environment-scope-in-pre-request-or-test-scripts/15889)):

> You should be able to accomplish by making use of `pm.sendRequest` and
> the [Postman API](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/631643/JsLs/#a237ffbe-0444-b394-a2c4-b99f691931cf). So you'd use `pm.sendRequest` to fetch the relevant
> Environment and save it to a local variable in your script and use it
> accordingly.
>
> More information here:
>
> https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts
>
> https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#defining-local-variables

There's a feature request in the Postman github repository for it: [Change environment scope in pre-request or test scripts #9061](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9061)